# Printing out array element

Tags: c, arrays, printf

So I have this code

```
double balance[5] = {1000.0, 2.0, 3.4, 17.0, 50.0};

printf("%d", balance[0]);
```

So I expect the first element of the array to print out, which would be 1000.0. However, it keeps on printing 0 for some odd reason. Anyone have an idea on why??

Comment: I used the %f format specifier and it gives me '0.00000'

Comment: try `printf("%0.1lf\n", balance[0]);` instead. Here is [your code](http://ideone.com/JA7hPt) on ideone. The problem is from somewhere else

Comment: Same output as before

Comment: It works now. I changed the array to a int array and forgot to change it back to a double

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From C11 draft

**§7.16.1.1/2**

```
...if type is not compatible with the type of the actual next argument 
(as promoted according to the default argument promotions), the behavior 
is undeﬁned, ....
```

You need to use correct format specifier to print the value of variable.

Comment: +1, finally somebody told the correct reason for the observed behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the format specifier of a `signed int` to print a `double`.
Use this-
`printf("%f", balance[0]);`

Answer (score 1):

To print `double`, use `%f`:

```
printf("%f", balance[0]);
```

You may be confused that **d** in `%d` means **double**, but actually it means **decimal**.

Comment: It prints out 0.00000

Comment: @user2930701 See http://ideone.com/lU2h8I and check your code again. BTW, to print one digit after decimal point like `1000.0`, use `%.1f`

Answer (score 1):

to print the double value you can not use `%d` you should use `%f` for that.

```
double balance[5] = {1000.0, 2.0, 3.4, 17.0, 50.0};

printf("%f", balance[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use %f instead of %d.You can also replace double with float.

float balance[5] = {1000.0, 2.0, 3.4, 17.0, 50.0};

printf("%f", balance[0])

1. %d is used for integer.
2. %f is used for float.

Answer (score 0):

You have used the wrong format specifier in the printf statment in your code. You are trying to print a floating point value using the %d format specifier which results in unexpected output.

Use **%f** in place of **%d** and everything will be all right, like this :

```
double balance[5] = {1000.0, 2.0, 3.4, 17.0, 50.0};
printf("%f", balance[0]);
```

**Output :**

```
1000.000000
```